# Is it possible to package a single-page html/javascript page and embed it in facebook similar to .swf flash embedded pages

Tags: facebook, html, flash, embed

It is possible to

- create an swf file
- and than create an html file that embeds it.
- This html file with the appropriate meta and link tags now becomes a url that when added to a facebook post produces a snippet attached to the post.
- The image of this snippet has a 'play' button which when clicked **plays the swf file in-situ**.

What I would like to do is have the same behavior except 'package' an html5 app as an swf.

Is such a thing possible?

Does actionscript allow one to simply call an html page within the flash container so users can interact with it?